# Google Biz listings -vs- Wikipedia display

Tags: seo, google, google-plus, knowledge-graph, user-reviews

I am having the discussion at work about whether or not to turn off our Google Business listing and G+ page because of the business reviews and star rating that appears on Google search results pages. Lets say that our reviews are not so favorable and we are sitting at a 1.9 star rating with about 30 reviews.

Of course in my industry the reviews only come when someone feels like complaining. Our service is pretty transparent and good reviews are hard to come by.

In any case, we have found that similar businesses around the country do not have a Google business listing page, nor a G+ page and that Wikipedia is what is displayed on the right hand side of the page where our business listing and ratings are shown.

I am against taking down our G+ and business listing page due to overall SEO implications. They are hoping that if we do this, and create a Wikipedia page, that it will replace our listings and ratings page.

I think it could kill our organic listings.

Anyone have any insight into this one way or another?

Comment: Perhaps addressing why you are getting low ratings would be a better business strategy.

Answer (score 1):

*Wikipedia doesn't mean you automatically get more rich search information*

This would mean your under the impression that having a Wikipedia page will automatically result in displaying that information, sadly its not as simple as that. Google uses a HUGE wide of selected online platforms to obtain additionally information and it extends far beyond Wikipedia, from stocks to external reviews. You must meet a lot of criteria to be featured additional information,  simply having a wikipedia page doesn't mean your get that information.

*Google Plus page is a plus!*

Most businesses will operate with multiple pages that includes both Google Plus pages and a Google Local Page (Business). A good example of this is dabs:

- Google search 'DABS' returns Wikipedia and Google Plus
- Google search 'DABS PLC' returns Google Local and Google Plus

The majority of big businesses in the UK operate this way and it works, but it doesn't mean this is the right method and is completely down to what you want. Some major companies prefer local search results because of the STARS...

Review stars a good indication of trust and obviously if you have bad reviews then you need to address that, but not having a Google plus or local page based on that is frankly non-sense and not addressing your real issue which is your product or services, and no matter what your SEO or rankings look like, that's what will make, or break you.

Comment: Your never be able to find the true value of either methods due to the fact its a kept secret and lack of case studies.